# Using VueJS Devtools Chrome Extension to debug another Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a chrome extension using **VueJS** that has a **VueJS** app to override the new tab window. However I am unable to get the **VueJS Devtools** extension working with it. With the new tab page open, I can verify that **VueJS** is working correctly in the console..

> You are running Vue in development mode.

however the Devtools plugin is unable to detect VueJS.

> Vue.js not detected

Does it have have something to do with extensions not being able to interact with each other?